# Shouldn't the score for tags be increased when an answer is accepted?

Tags: discussion, tag-score

Currently the score for a tag is based on the number of upvotes the answerer received for answers to questions with a particular tag.

But there are cases where the answer is accepted by the user, but it doesn't get any upvotes, and in that case score for the tag doesn't increase

The answerer gets reputation when his answer is either accepted or upvoted. Shouldn't the same logic be applied when calculating the score for each tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accepted answers:

- Are only something that the OP can bestow or remove
- Only count as 15 reputation
- Only substantially matter to the OP as, "This answer helped me best"

Upvotes:

- Are something *everyone* with the privilege can bestow or remove
- Count as 10 reputation
- Are the signal that we send to the rest of the world that shows this answer is "best"

With the above said, applying that to tag scores would be awkward.  The community hasn't weighed in to say that your answer is good; only the OP has said that this answer fixed them.  That doesn't necessarily indicate that you're knowledgeable in a tag, just that you're good at solving specific problems.